# How would I parse an entire XML file that is possibly malformed?

Tags: c#, xml, exception, malformed

So far, what I'm doing is:

```
try 
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = loadXml(orderFilePath);
}
catch (XmlException exception)
{
    //... blah blah - there was an error, let the user know
}
```

But I would really like to be able to attempt to parse the file anyway.  When I say "malformed" I don't necessarily mean that there will be an unclosed tag or element, but that there might be something like one of the following included in an element's value: '<', '>', '&'

I've seen mentioned around that I would probably have to use XmlReader - but would that still throw an exception on that element, or allow me to fix the problem in some way?

I know fixing the XML at the source is the best solution, but I do not control where the XML is coming from.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Super simple example of the XML:

```
<Order>
  <Customer_ID>555-555-5555</Customer_ID>
  <ShipToAddress>
    <Customer_Name>Some Guy</Customer_Name>
    <Street>123 Fake Dr.</Street>
    <Street2></Street2>
    <City>West Palm Beach</City>
    <State>FL</State>
    <ZipCode>33417</ZipCode>
    <Country>United States</Country>
  </ShipToAddress>
  <BillToAddress>
    <Customer_Name>Some Guy</Customer_Name>
    <Street>123 Fake Dr.</Street>
    <Street2></Street2>
    <City>West Palm Beach</City>
    <State>FL</State>
    <ZipCode>33417</ZipCode>
    <Country>United States</Country>
  </BillToAddress>
  <items>
    <item>
      <Product_ID>25101</Product_ID>
      <Product_Name></Product_Name>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <USPrice>26.95000</USPrice>
    </item>
  </items>
<!-- bad stuff here -->
<How_did_you_hear_about_us>Coffee & Tea magazine</How_did_you_hear_about_us>
<!-- bad stuff here -->
</Order>
```

The thing is - I don't necessarily know if it will always be in the same place.

Comment: Give a clearer example of the malformed XML.

Comment: you may need to just read the file first and use regular expressions to match and replace unescaped characters with escaped versions, then reread the document as XML. You'd have to ascertain what can be malformed and how it would be fixed in order to craft your expression. Maybe you can assume XML tags are always well formed, and therefore replace any stray brackets with their escaped versions which are assumed to be intended to be read as text

Comment: Malformed XML is not XML. You should treat it as text file and read appropriately... Maybe some HTML parser would work (i.e. I'd try HtmlAgilityPack).

Comment: You are on hiding to nothing with this. String replace would sort all the errors you know about and these might be simple enough to get away with regex. You could use XmlReader and spot the the bad xml, better still you could come up with a schema and do the same, but when you detect an issue, what happens next?

Comment: I see now. You could definitely whip up some regex to look between `>` and `<` and replace `&` with something else.

Comment: @tnw It was a thought that I had, too, but I wasn't sure, and I thought I'd come here to ask the experts.  ;)

That's what I'll have to do.  I don't like taking care of other people's problems, but sometimes I don't have a choice.

Comment: @Zaemz I know it's not C#, but check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473417/powershell-regex-to-replace-xml-tag-values). It looks like pretty much the exact same problem you're having. One of the answers has the regex you need too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be to validate a few things before parsing it. You could use a regex to validate the XML tags, but perhaps more easier could be a `Stack` where you add every `<` and `>` symbol on. Afterwards just loop trough it and assert that you don't get the same symbol twice in a row.

This raises the question: how do you distinguish between `<MyElement>>` and `<MyEl>ement>`?

This is all pretty vague though: what do you want to happen when the XML turns out to be invalid? How far do you want to take this pre-processing validation?

I believe that the best option here is to not proceed. You can't fix every issue with malformed XML thrown at you and it might just be better to inform the user and make that the end.

If the source is consistently sending malformed XML at you, you'll have to contact the maintainers or look for alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, Jeroen.  I agree with you.  I'll make a note to those responsible for the XML.  I was thinking of only going so far as to correct the problem with a node's value.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned - there are a couple of things to do here:

Step 1 - Find out whether XML is malformed on not. For both Element and Value (or Attribute)
Solution: Use Regex or load through String Builder and parse/look for characters (Regex is always better)

Step 2: You can also form an XSD if you want to validate that certain elements have always come (bare minimum). Based on workflow - if those dont appear - you can throw error - depends on your workflow

Step 3: Once you have parsed/fixed the XML - you then need to consume the values
Solution: LINQ to XML is really a good approach here to pull values for what you are interested and not malformed